# Mutate and ifelse() fail when logical check tail&head values of the column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and I want to add new column `ex` by conditional checking `tail` and `head` values of the another column.If the condition is match, insert `ex1` or `ex2` to new column. 
Here is what I mean

```
x = rep(c(seq(1,3),seq(2,3)),2)
grp=gl(2,5)
df <- data.frame(x,grp)


#       x grp
#    1  1   1
#    2  2   1
#    3  3   1
#    4  2   1
#    5  3   1
#    6  1   2
#    7  2   2
#    8  3   2
#    9  2   2
#    10 3   2
```

I tried

library(dplyr)

```
dff <- df%>%
group_by(grp)%>%
mutate(ex=ifelse(tail(x,2)==c(2,3),tail(ex,2)="ex2"&head(ex,3)="ex1",NA))

>Error: unexpected '=' in:
"group_by(grp)%>%
mutate(ex=ifelse(tail(x,2)==c(2,3),tail(ex,2)="
```

expected output

```
 #          x grp  ex
    #    1  1   1  ex1 
    #    2  2   1  ex1
    #    3  3   1  ex1
    #    4  2   1  ex2
    #    5  3   1  ex2
    #    6  1   2  ex1
    #    7  2   2  ex1 
    #    8  3   2  ex1
    #    9  2   2  ex2
    #    10 3   2  ex2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: didn't get you. could you explain that a bit more by taking one example? What do you mean by `x column tail and head values` ?

Comment: @RonakShah x column head 3 values (1,2,3) and tail 2 values (2,3). That is what I meant.

Comment: How do we come to know head has 3 values and tail 2 ?

Comment: @RonakShah you just want to create `ex` column based on tail 2 values matching to (2,3) then this two row are `ex2` and rest of them `ex1`. you can see it from the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, .I[tail(seq_len(.N),2)] , grp]$V1
df[, ex:= "ex1"]
df[df[i1, .I[x==c(2,3)] , grp]$V1, ex := "ex2"]
df
#   x grp  ex
#1: 1   1 ex1
#2: 2   1 ex1
#3: 3   1 ex1
#4: 2   1 ex2
#5: 3   1 ex2
#6: 1   2 ex1
#7: 2   2 ex1
#8: 3   2 ex1
#9: 2   2 ex2
#10:3   2 ex2
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp) %>%
   mutate(x1 = rep(c(0, 2,3), c(n()-2, 1, 1)), 
          ex = if_else(x1==x & row_number() %in% tail(row_number(), 2), "ex2", "ex1")) %>%
   select(-x1)
#      x    grp    ex
#   <int> <fctr> <chr>
#1      1      1   ex1
#2      2      1   ex1
#3      3      1   ex1
#4      2      1   ex2
#5      3      1   ex2
#6      1      2   ex1
#7      2      2   ex1
#8      3      2   ex1
#9      2      2   ex2
#10     3      2   ex2
```

Comment: Is there also `dplyr` way?

Comment: @Alexander Updated with a dplyr way

Comment: Wow. I wasn't expected such complicated code. But that's fine! Thanks man

Comment: @Alexander The problem is that you are comparing multiple values to the column and we have to make the lengths same while comparing.  The `rep` step create another column with 2, 3 filling the last elements while 0 or any other value occupy the rest.  In case, there are 0 values in the original column 'x', we make it false with the second condition `row_number() %in% tail(..`